# Automatic CSV Import Error: Tab already exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recently tried to import keyword data via csv to google sheets. that script works fine. Now I tried to customize this script for another task. To import Website SEO Audit Data. Instead of 6 files I got now 14 Files. I changed the Name of the Tabs, the regex selector and changes the increment from 6 to 14 in the for loops. But for any reason when I run this script it says Tab "Backlinks" already exists after it is created. Any idea what's wrong with this code? When I delete the Backlinks loop and run script it says the same error with Anchors loop. Any idea what's wrong with it?

I just can't find the error.

Here is the Google Apps Script Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onOpen() {

  var menuEntries = [ 
                     {name: "  Build up the Competitor report", functionName: "Build"},
                     {name: "  free for another script", functionName: "insert here the function name"}
                    ];

  ss.addMenu("AHREFS Import Tools", menuEntries);
}

function Build() {

  var rename = "Competitortemp";     //Browser.inputBox("Insert here the Folder Name");

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  ss.insertSheet('PlaceHolder');
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
      case "PlaceHolder":
        break;
      default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(rename).next().getId();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id); 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','Id']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    var tabs = []
    tabs.push(file.getName(),file.getId())
    list.push(tabs);
  }

  for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++) {
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /backlinksimilarlinks-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);

    if (match != null) {
      ss.insertSheet('Backlinks');
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Backlinks');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable number of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sh.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sh.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      sh.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

  for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++) {
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /referringdomains-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);

    if (match != null) {
      ss.insertSheet('Referring domains');
      var sp = ss.getSheetByName('Referring domains');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");

      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sp.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sp.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sp.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

  for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++) {
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /anchors-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);

    if (match != null) {
      ss.insertSheet('Anchors');
      var se = ss.getSheetByName('Anchors');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");

      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        se.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = se.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      se.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

  for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++) {
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /referring-ips-by-subnets/;
    var match = re.exec(string);

    if (match != null) {
      ss.insertSheet('Referring IPs');
      var sq = ss.getSheetByName('Referring IPs');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");

      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sq.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 
    var re = /internalbacklinksimilarlinks/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Internal Links');
      var sr = ss.getSheetByName('Internal Links');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");

      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sr.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sr.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sr.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

  for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /organic-keywords/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Organiac Keywords');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Organic Keywords');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

    for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /top-pages-by-traffic/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Top Pages');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Top Pages');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

    for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /top-subfolders/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Top Folders');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Top Folders');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

    for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /best-pages-by-links-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Best Pages by Links');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Best Pages by Links');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

      for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /best-pages-by-links-growth/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Best Pages by Link Growth');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Best Pages by Link Growth');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

    for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /linkeddomains-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Externe Links');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Externe Links');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

    for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /linkeddomains-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Linked Domains');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Linked Domains');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

    for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /-linkedanchors-subdomains/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Linked Anchors');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Linked Anchors');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

      for(i = 1;i <= 14;i++){
    var string =   list[i][0]
    var re = /brokenlinks/;
    var match = re.exec(string);
    if (match != null){
      ss.insertSheet('Broken Links');
      var sd = ss.getSheetByName('Broken Links');
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(string)
      var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('utf-16LE'); //note the charset
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,"\t");
      //unless you csv has variable amount of columns per line, you should do this
      if(csvData.length > 0) {

        sd.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      } else
        throw 'Blank file';

      var range = sd.getRange('A1:L1')
      range.setBackground('#000000')
      range.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sd.autoResizeColumns(1, 12)
    }
  }

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PlaceHolder');
  ss.deleteSheet(sheet);
  ///////

   Files = folder.getFiles();

    while (Files.hasNext()) {
      var File = Files.next().setTrashed(true);
    }  
  //////
}
```

Comment: Would you please run the script. When you get an error  for "Backlinks" failure, please copy the full Execution transcript into your question.

Comment: I also suggest some simple troubleshooting. Insert the line "Logger.log("string = "+string+", match = "+match+", and the code found a match");" after  `var re = /backlinksimilarlinks-subdomains/;var match = re.exec(string);if (match != null){` Run the script and look at the log. At least you'll see the values of the string and match that are causing the errors; my wild guess is that it is finding two matches. FWIW, another possibility is that the check for null is not working. I often find it easier to test the length of the string, such as `if (match.length !=0).

Answer (score 0):

+You are employing a for loop and during each iteration you deploy the `ss.insertSheet();` method, in case your `if` condition is fulfilled.

+If you get the error "Tab already exists" it means that your if contition is fullfilled more than one time.

### The reason is the structure of your arrays,

as you can verify with `Logger.log(list[]);`

You append during each `while` loop additional data to the array `tabs` and append the always longer getting array multiple times to the array `list` - as a result, some of the data will be contained in several array elements of `list` and your `if` condition will be fulfilled multiple times.

> To avoid it, modify your code from
> `tabs.push(file.getName(),file.getId())` to
> `tabs=[file.getName(),file.getId()]`

Comment: I tried it but still throws out same error. you mean in line 39, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Could you log list (Logger.log(list);)  after list.push(tabs); and see if your list contains your Regex expression twice? This is what would give you an error. Either because you pushed the same file name twice into the array, or because you have on your drive two documents with the same / similar name (containing the Regex expression in their file name).